# For which values of $x$ the vectors span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> For which values of x, the vectors $v_1=(1,x^2,x)$ and $v=(1,1,1)$ span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For every such $x$, find an equation of the corresponding plane.

Am I correct in saying that the vectors span a plane if they are linearly dependent? In that case, the vectors are linearly dependent if $x = 1$ or $x= -1$. How can you find an equation of the corresponding plane if $x = 1$?

Comment: Quite the opposite, actually: they span a plane if they’re _independent_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plane is a vector space of dimension $\mathbf{2}$. So, you would need the vectors to be linearly **in**depedent.

For $2$ vectors, it is easy to test linear independence. For if they are linearly dependent, then one of them is a scalar multiple of the other.

Note that your $v_1$ already has the first coordinate $1.$ So the only way they are linearly dependent is if all the coordinates are equal. This directly gives you that $x = 1.$

Thus, the two vectors span a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only iff $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$.

In this case, you can find a vector perpendicular to both $v_1$ and $v.$
One of them would be $v_1 \times v = (x^2 - x, x-1, 1 - x^2).$

The plane will be given as $(x^2 - x) X + (x - 1)Y + (1 - x^2)Z = 0.$ (Note that the origin is a point lying on the plane.)

Another way to represent the plane would be: $t v_1 + uv$ where $t, u \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

No. If they are linearly dependent, then the span a *line*, not a plane. In fact, $v_1$ and $v$ span a plane if and only if they are linearly **in**dependent. And that occurs if and only if $x\neq1$. In that case, $v_1$ and $v$ span the plan$$\{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in\mathbb R^3\mid-x\alpha-\beta+(x+1)\gamma=0\}.$$

Comment: Ok thanks. If a set of three vectors are dependent, do they span a plane?

Comment: They *can* span a plane. Or a line. Or $\{0\}$.

Comment: How did you calculate the plane here?

Comment: Such a plane $P$ is of the form $\{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in\mathbb R^3\mid a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma=0\}$, for some numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$. In order to find these numbers, I solved the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+b+c=0(\iff(1,1,1)\in P)\\a+x^2b+xc=0(\iff(1,x^2,x)\in P)\end{array}\right.$$and one of the solutions is $(a,b,c)=(-x,-1,x+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a simple way to find an equation of the plane, when the vectors are linearly independent (which happens if $x\ne 1$ only, b.t.w.)

For the sake of clearness, I'll denote $v_1=(1,\xi^2,\xi)$. The vector $u=(x,y,z)$ is in the plane generated by $v_1$ and $v$ if and only if the vectors $v_1,v,u$ are linearly dependent, i.e. if their determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x&1&1\\
y&\xi^2&1  \\
z&\xi&1
\end{vmatrix}=0.$$